# It is possible to debug an asp.net WebForms application on MacOS using Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

Current scenario is that I have this macos laptop (Apple M1 Pro processor) in which I was working for the last 8 months on react under visual studio code. Now, in a new project I need to leverage some API's and a lot of JSON responses and I wanted to debug the code but I saw that it is just not possible. I came across this old article [ASP.NET Mono Setup](https://blog.coderscoffeehouse.com/tech/2016-01-19-aspnet-linux-setup/)

but I still feel that I won't be able to have the same level of developing experience like in a windows machine.

So, question is, can I (and if the answer if yes) debug an asp.net webforms app on visual studio 2022 for mac? If not, I would need to ask for a laptop replacement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Webforms only exist on the full / legacy / Windows-only .NET framework (v1.0 through 4.8.x) - which is **not** supported on Mac OS. So I believe you won't be able to run and debug a Webforms app on a Mac  - sorry

Comment: @marc_s I believe Mono changes the equation a bit there, as you can run ASP.NET Framework (non-Core) apps on Mono. However, the only IDE I know of that really supports Web Forms is Visual Studio on Windows, so the experience would be rather painful on MacOS. Perhaps JetBrains has something, but running it on Apple Silicon is probably not going to go over well. If you're going to do Web Forms, the only satisfying way of going about is to run Visual Studio on Windows. Perhaps someone else has figured out another combination that works, but I doubt it.

Comment: I believe you can run X86_64 Windows on Apple Silicon (M1) macOS in a VM (using emulation), so that might possibly be an option for you without replacing your entire PC. You'd have to research what that experience is like, I can't confess to having tried it, and I know things tend to change often as different virtualization apps like Parallels and VMWare start adding more features.

Comment: Please go ahead and ask for a laptop replacement. Mono ASP.NET hasn't been updated for years, so unless you accept problems here and there you should well go back to Windows https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/

Answer (score 0):

Only the .net core runtimes are platform neutral.

But, the .net 2-4.8 runtimes are not.

One MIGHT be able to play and mess around with mono, but at the end of the day, I suggest you go with a VM (virtual machine),and run windows.

In other words, you don't need a new laptop, but just use a VM and install windows on that VM.

Comment: doesn't that slows down my mac?

Comment: You mean using a vm? Well, sure, but these days, with lots of ram, and lots of CPU cores, then no, it not a big deal. I mean, I have what, 15+ VM's. I have one for SharePoint, one for SERVER 2016, one for DOS 5.0,  I have one for windows 7. I mean, how can you test any software? And really fantastic is that you can roll back changes. So, when testing a installer etc., you can start out with a clean machine. VM's are to developers what Word Processing is to a office assistant doing work.  VM's are a must have. Say you need a web server + 2 client computer. Just spool all them up and you testing